# Are changes in the sub-collection in a Firestore document gonna trigger the EventListeners of the parent document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
orders(document)
   date: xxx
   quantity: xxx
   chats(collection)
      message(document)
         txt: xxx
         date: xxx
```

Are documents added in chats collection gonna trigger the orders document's EventListener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both reads and listeners are shallow in Firestore. If you attach a listener to the order document, that listener won't be triggered by writes to its chats subcollection.